# Is using .. as parent directory cross platform?

Tags: cross-platform, parent, directory-structure

More as a curiosity, if I want to prevent some code from looking at the parent directory (contained in a list of files/directories) and I do something along the lines of (e.g. Perl) `next if /^.+$/` to exclude . and .. , is this sufficiently cross-platform? If not, which platforms are different and how might one prevent accessing the parent in that case?

Comment: It doesn't work on VMS or Mac OS (prior to OS X), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work in most modern platforms.  (It will also exclude Unix hidden files/directories, but this is probably a good thing given the context.)  Windows has a special case at the root of a drive, but it's not so much "different syntax" as "not there in any syntax"; if you have any intention of using platforms such as OpenVMS or Z/OS, it won't work at all.

Note that Perl and Python ship with cross-platform path utilities that you should use instead.  I couldn't tell you about PHP or Ruby but I presume both also do so.

Comment: As I commented to Amadan, the `$` matches the end of the line so I don't ignore `.string` just `.` and `..` and `...` etc.

Comment: I was going to show you that I was already using a platform independent library (p3rl.org/File::chdir) but needed to do this one thing by hand. In doing so I was going to show that the function I needed wasn't available, and while doing that I found the function I needed (File::Spec::Functions::no_upwards). Still its nice to know which OSes treat this situation differently, so I don't regret asking the question! Thanks for pushing me to re-examine the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work in ZX Spectrum. :)

Seriously, pretty much all platforms in current wide use (i.e. MSDOS, Windows, *NIX including Linux) conform to that. Be aware you will also be excluding hidden directories in UNIX-like systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the `$` matches the end of the line so I don't ignore `.string` just `.` and `..` and `...` etc.